# $\mathbb{T} \to \Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$ is surjective, where $\Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$ is the set of characters of $l^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $l^1(\mathbb{Z})$ be the collection of all complex valued functions $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, where $$\Vert f \Vert_1 = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |f(n)| < \infty$$

Define multiplication in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ as $$f*g(m) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(m-n)g(n)$$

Then under the $\Vert \Vert_1$ norm this becomes a unital Banach algebra with unit,
$$
 \chi_0(m) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $m=0$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

In general, let
$$
 \chi_i(m) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $m=i$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then we get that $$\chi_i*\chi_j = \chi_{i+j}$$
Therefore we can write $$\chi_n = \underbrace{\chi_1*\chi_1* \cdots *\chi_1}_{n \text{ times}} = (\chi_1)^n$$

Now if $f \in l^1(\mathbb{Z})$,
\begin{equation}f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n) \chi_n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n) (\chi_1)^n
\end{equation}

Let $\Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$ be the character space of $l^1(\mathbb{Z})$. What I have to show is the existence of a bijection from the unit circle, $\mathbb{T}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$. I have proved the map from $\mathbb{T} \to \Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$ defined as $$z \to \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty f(n)z^n$$

is injective.

But I am confused about proving the surjectivity of the map. From above I see that if $\tau \in \Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z}))$, $\tau$ is completely characterized by its image of $\chi_1$. So, it is enough to show that if $\tau \in \Omega(l^1(\mathbb{Z})$, then $\tau(\chi_1) \in \mathbb{T}$.

Comment: Any character is a bounded linear functional on $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z}).$ Therefore $M\ge |\tau(\chi_n)|=|\tau(\chi_1)|^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$ It is possible iff $\tau(\chi_1)\in \mathbb{T}.$

Comment: From the fact that $\tau$ is a bounded linear functional I get $\tau(\chi_1)$ should lie in the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. But what enforces $|\tau(\chi_1)| = 1$?

Comment: Ok I get it. I just need to employ the same reason why $|\tau(\chi_1)| ≤ 1$ to $\chi_1^{-1}$